# How to call a AngularJS controller using onclick event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, controller

This is my code in javascript.

```
    function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('<c:url value='/learningresources/ajaxvalue'/>').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.response = data;
    });
 }
```

This code gets a list of records from spring controller. I want this same to return the result bu onclick event.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function for ng-click like:-

HTML:-

```
<button ng-click="clickme()">Click me</button>
```

Controller:-

```
$scope.clickme=function(){
   $http.get('<c:url value='/learningresources/ajaxvalue'/>').
     success(function(data) {
       $scope.response = data;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

javaScript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.clickFun = function(){
        $http.get('<c:url value='/learningresources/ajaxvalue'/>').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.response = data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="yourCtrl">
    <button ng-click="clickFun()">Your btn</button>
</div>
```

This works!